# How do I pass an array of character pointers as void *, then cast back to array of character pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void, void-pointers

I'm passing an array of character pointers to `sqlite3_exec`, which takes 1 parameter and presents it as a `void *`, but then I want to access it as the array of character pointers in the callback function.

```
char *output_params[] = {"one", "two"};
result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_statement, callback, output_params, &zErrMsg);

....

static int callback(void *param, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    // How do I access my character array?
    char *output_params[2] = (char **)param;
}
```

How do I access it after I pass it?

Comment: How about `char **output_params = param;`, and access the `char *`s with `output_params[0]`, `output_params[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
int callback(void *param, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    const char** p = (const char **)param;
    printf("%s\n", p[0]);
    printf("%s\n", p[1]);
}
```

Here's simple program that demonstrates the concept.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void* in)
{
    char **p = (char**)in;
    printf("%s\n", p[0]);
    printf("%s\n", p[1]);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char *output_params[] = {"one", "two"};
   foo(output_params);
}
```